# Position of ‘was’ in reported speech

Tags: questions, reported-speech

Let’s say someone I know visited a doctor. Do the following sentences mean the same?

1. What did the doctor say the problem was?
2. What did the doctor say was the problem?

I am pretty sure the first one is correct, but the second one also sounds like it could be.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no preposition in your sentences at all.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences mean the same thing, however, I wouldn't use the second sentence. While the entire construction is a little awkward, the second sentence is too awkward to use.

If you want to shorten the sentence you can eliminate some of the awkwardness:

> What did the doctor say?